# PyMySQL InterfaceError and "already closed" error

Tags: python, flask, pymysql

I'm writing a flask program and using PyMySQL to connect to my database. When enter the function that executes SQL it works the first time, but when its called again I get interface error and subsequently already closed error. I'm assuming this is because the connection was already closed but nowhere in my code do I close the connection.

```
[2021-09-11 14:11:14,725] ERROR in app: Exception on /registration [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\routes.py", line 80, in registration
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 547, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 793, in _execute_command
    raise err.InterfaceError(0, "")
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\\routes.py", line 82, in registration
    connection.commit()
  File "C:\Users\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 360, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 404, in close
    raise err.Error("Already closed")
pymysql.err.Error: Already closed
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2021 14:11:14] "GET /registration HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Is `connection.commit()` in routes.py closing the connection? Also in connections.py line 360 what is calling `self.close()`. Is that what's causing my error?

Thanks

Comment: No, `connection.commit()` doesn't close the connection.

Comment: Are you using `with` to manage the connection with a context manager? That will automatically close it when you leave the `with` block.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I'm using a with block, that should be the problem. Thanks.